# Python Turtle draw centered square

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I need to draw a square given a center point using the turtle module.

```
def drawCentSq(t,center,side):
    xPt=center[0]
    yPt=center[1]
    xPt-=int(side/side)
    yPt+=int(side/side)
    t.up()
    t.goto(xPt,yPt)
    t.down()
    for i in range(4):
        t.forward(side)
        t.right(90)
```

def main():

```
import turtle        
mad=turtle.Turtle()
wn=mad.getscreen()
print(drawCentSq(mad,(0,0),50))
main()
```

I'm having a hard time making my turtle go to the right starting point.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
xPt-=int(side/2.0)
yPt+=int(side/2.0)
```

As it was you were just += and -= 1.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to draw a square given a center point using the turtle module.

As @seth notes, you can do this by fixing the center calculation in your code:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def drawCentSq(turtle, center, side):

    """ A square is a series of perpendicular sides """

    xPt, yPt = center

    xPt -= side / 2
    yPt += side / 2

    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(xPt, yPt)
    turtle.down()

    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(side)
        turtle.right(90)

yertle = Turtle()

drawCentSq(yertle, (0, 0), 50)

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

But let's step back and consider how else we can draw a square at a given point of a given size.  Here's a completely different solution:

```
def drawCentSq(turtle, center, side):

    """ A square is a circle drawn at a rough approximation """

    xPt, yPt = center

    xPt -= side / 2
    yPt -= side / 2

    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(xPt, yPt)
    turtle.right(45)
    turtle.down()

    turtle.circle(2**0.5 * side / 2, steps=4)

    turtle.left(45)  # return cursor to original orientation
```

And here's yet another:

```
STAMP_UNIT = 20

def drawCentSq(turtle, center, side):

    """ A square can be stamped directly from a square cursor """

    mock = turtle.clone()  # clone turtle to avoid cleaning up changes
    mock.hideturtle()
    mock.shape("square")
    mock.fillcolor("white")
    mock.shapesize(side / STAMP_UNIT)

    mock.up()
    mock.goto(center)

    return mock.stamp()
```

Note that this solution returns a stamp ID that you can pass to `yertle`'s `clearstamp()` method to remove the square from the screen if/when you wish.